# Is there any shortcut key to put quotation mark on character I have on R file?

Tags: r

I have a lot of these on my R file:

```
    c(Johnny Bladel,Ball, Ball, Called Strike, 15 Johnny Bladel putout                                                          
    (4-3) for out number 1)
```

I just copied and pasted this from website and I need to put quotation mark on anything that is between quotation marks. Like this:

```
     c("Johnny Bladel","Ball", "Ball", "Called Strike", "15 Johnny Bladel putout(4-3) for out number 1")
```

Is there any hot key on Rstudio that allows me to do this automatically?

Comment: You can find and replace , with ", " and add in the beginning and trailing " yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `scan` the file and remove the `c(` and `)` at the end

```
v1 <- gsub("^c\\(|\\)$" , "", trimws(scan("yourfile.txt", what = "", sep=",", quiet=TRUE)))
dput(v1)
#c("Johnny Bladel", "Ball", "Ball", "Called Strike", "15 Johnny Bladel putout (4-3) for out number 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if there is any such key in Rstudio or not but you can edit the file in vi editor in multiple steps. There might be a more elegant way of doing it but this should also do the job

```
%s/^/"/g
%s/$/"/g
%s/,/","/g
%s/" /"/g
```